# Access current node in an existing block

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I am using Drupal Lightning and a bootstrap subtheme. I have a requirement to place a section of the node page template in another block region. So I need to access the nodes fields in that block, fields like the taxonomy, block, breadcrumbs. Example my node--page.html.twig template prints these fields:

```
{{ node.title.value }}
{{ content.field_text }}
{{ drupal_view('mysection', 'block_1') }}
{{ drupal_block('mytheme_breadcrumbs') }}
```

It also has an includes template

```
{% include '@mytheme/includes/section.html.twig' %}
```

I can print these fields fine in a node template

```
node--page.html.twig
```

But I need to print these fields outside of the node template and into a block. I tried to create a View block and set a contextual filter "Content ID from URL" Then placed the View block in a region and then in the region template I tried to access the node fields from my region template but could not. I can access the title and body fields. This is the template.

```
region--myregion.html.twig
```

I then tried Entity blocks. I created a new block of type Entity view (Content). I tried to access the node fields from my region template but could not.

```
block--entityviewcontent.html.twig
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Enable debug

by going in `sites/default/` and copying the file `default.services.yml` to `services.yml`  and modifying the following lines

```
cache: false
debug: true
```

### Turn browser comments on

make sure your browser has Comments enabled (some browsers have them disabled by default for example in chrome in inspector on the 3 dot menu click `settings` and `preferences` find `Show HTML comments`

### Find out which twig template is used

after that inspect the code in near the block that you want to override and you should see something similar to this

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'block' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--block-name.html.twig
   * block--block-content--b436f9c6-34ae-4879-8b55-068015a999d3.html.twig
   * block--block-content--bundle-name.html.twig
   * block--block-content.html.twig
   * block--block-content.html.twig
   x block.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/block/block--system.html.twig' -->
```

you can get the twig block template from the location in comment `BEGIN OUTPUT`

### Use and modify template

Copy this twig file into your theme `templates` folder and rename to any name above.  Modify the code and add something similar to the twig block template you just created

```
{% if nid %}
    nid:{{nid}} <br/>
    title:{{node_title}} <br/>
    body:{{body}}<br/>
    text:{{field_text}} <br/>    
{% endif %}
```

### Expose node variable to block templates

Add into your THEMENAME.theme the following code or similar

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_block(&$vars){
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      // You can get nid and anything else you need from the node object.
      $vars["nid"] = $node->id();
      $vars["node_title"] = $node->getTitle();
      $vars["body"] = $node->body->value;
      $vars["field_text"] = $node->field_text->value;

      //following did not work ?!
      //$vars["field_text"] = $node->get('field_text')->getValue();
      //$vars["field_text"] = $node->field_text->getValue();
    }    
}
```

### Clear cache

with the above you are making the node fields available to block templates

Comment: Will doing it in this method give me the same access to a node like I have when using the node template: node--page.html.twig. I am going to try to print a partial included template, taxonomy field and a block {{ drupal_block('my theme_breadcrumbs') }} {{ drupal_view('section', 'block_1') }}

Comment: Not sure how much time I can devote on help or tutoring but you can always shoot me a message and will see ... about the 2nd question I think you have to insert what you will need in the block template inside the `_preprocess_block` function